# Formatting print statements with escape characters

Tags: java

I'm having an issue getting my columns to line up correctly. All I have to do is take input from the user and then print ASCII character values for letters in one column, ASCII values for numbers in the next column, and then print a column for Hex values based on input entered.
Everything prints fine except for when I include numbers in my input. When that happens, my hex values for the numbers tabs out one too many times, and everything else stays lined up perfectly.

I have spent hours on this trying to change \t's in different places and I am just at a loss and wondered if anyone could offer me any suggestions. 
Also, I'm not allowed to use printf for this assignment, so I believe I am locked into using escape characters to format my print statements.

Thanks in advance for any tips or suggestions!

```
// This program gets input as a string, then outputs the initial characters,
// ASCII values of the characters and numbers, and hex values for each character.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CZUnit3Ch12 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //***** Variable Declaration **********
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;
        int i;
        char character;
        //****** End Variable Declaration *********

        //****** Begin Program *********

        System.out.print("Please enter a string of any length: ");
        userInput = stdIn.nextLine();
        stdIn.close();  // close the scanner; not used anymore


        System.out.print("Initial\t\tASCII (char) \t\tASCII (int)\t\tHex\n");       // headings for each column

        for (i = 0; i<userInput.length(); i++)
        {
            character = userInput.charAt(i);

            System.out.print(userInput.charAt(i) + "\t");

            if(Character.isDigit(character))
            {
                System.out.print("\t\t\t");
                System.out.print("\t"+Integer.toString(userInput.charAt(i)));
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("\t" + Integer.toString(userInput.charAt(i)) + "\t");
                System.out.print("\t");
            }


            System.out.print("\t\t\t\t"+Integer.toHexString(character).toUpperCase());
            System.out.print("\n");

        } // end for

        System.out.println(""); // blank line for spacing

        System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");   
    } // end main

} // end class CZUnit3Ch12.java
```

Comment: Tabs are not standardized to a specific width.  If you want to guarantee things lining up in all cases, use only spaces.  Look at `System.out.printf()`

Comment: Well my professor limited us to using escape sequences for spacing. I had written the whole program out initially using the printf statement when the professor posted in a thread that he didn't want us to use printf.. :(

Comment: So you'll have to assume a fixed width for tabs (i.e. 8) and then carefully count characters of each output field so you insert only the required number of tabs.  As to the question, please visit the [help] and read [ask].  You should write a little testcase, aka a [mcve], to demonstrate the issue you are having, Also include the expected output and the actual output.  In writing the [mcve] you are likely to answer your own question, and if you don't you now have a testcase anybody can run.

Comment: If you reduce your vertical spacing, you don't need to name your closing braces with comments. Such comments are only helpful in the chapter of a book, where scope is demonstrated. It should not be intended as a habit.

Answer (score 1):

I remember doing a similar assignment in school and using `\t` worked out fine. 
I tried your code and noticed that it only messes up the tabbing when the user inputs numbers, since it's skipping a column. If you adjust the tabbing to accommodate this, things line up.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //***** Variable Declaration **********
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput;
    int i;
    char character;

    boolean bIsDigit = false;
    //****** End Variable Declaration *********

    //****** Begin Program *********

    System.out.print("Please enter a string of any length: ");
    userInput = stdIn.nextLine();
    stdIn.close();  // close the scanner; not used anymore


    System.out.print("\n\nInitial\t\tASCII (char) \t\tASCII (int)\t\tHex\n");       // headings for each column

    for (i = 0; i<userInput.length(); i++)
    {
        character = userInput.charAt(i);

        System.out.print(userInput.charAt(i) + "\t");

        if(Character.isDigit(character))
        {
            bIsDigit = true;
            System.out.print("\t\t\t");
            System.out.print("\t"+Integer.toString(userInput.charAt(i)));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("\t" + Integer.toString(userInput.charAt(i)) + "\t");
            System.out.print("\t");
        }

        if(bIsDigit)
            System.out.print("\t\t\t"+Integer.toHexString(character).toUpperCase());
        else
            System.out.print("\t\t\t\t"+Integer.toHexString(character).toUpperCase());

        System.out.print("\n");
        bIsDigit = false;

    } // end for

    System.out.println(""); // blank line for spacing

    System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");   
} // end main
```

Please try it: http://rextester.com/VLZ70001

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't read your problem statement very well... you know that it only messes up when numbers are entered. All you have to do is when you check if it's a digit, set a flag, and print out one less tab to line up correctly under the hex column. Then set the flag back to false for the next character. I'm sure there are other solutions, but this is one way to do it.

Comment: That makes sense! So by "setting up a flag", do you mean using a boolean, if statement, or something like that? This is only my second Java course in school, so I'm still very new to this. Thanks for your help, DigitalNinja!

Comment: Yes, by "flag", I mean a Boolean variable, because when you set it to true/false it's like raising/lowering a flag (a common term used for Boolean variables in programming) that usually signals something different should happen (like doing `this` instead of `that`). Good luck!